# jQuery working only upon reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

On [this WordPress site](https://dev.mattress-guides.net/test/), I use a site-wide script to add information to outgoing links.

However, it only works if the page is reloaded or the user navigates to any second page.

Assuming it was a jQuery loading time issue, I added a timer to wait for it, but it doesn't make any difference: the message "jQuery loaded!" appears but the `click` function seems not to be working.

When the page is reloaded, the `click` function works as expected.

Here is the code:

```
var jQloaded = setInterval(function() {
   if (window.jQuery) {
      console.log("jQuery Loaded!");
      clearInterval(jQloaded);

      jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[href*="/external/"]', (function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert('ok');
      }));
   }
}, 50);
```

I tried everything I could think of without success. Can you tell me what's wrong?

PS: to replicate the behavior it's necessary to open a fresh incognito/private window. Emptying the cache + hard reload isn't enough.

Comment: Have you tried: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @AdamMcquiff - I did now and it works! But why? Isn't the delegation supposed to work on any elements added later?

Comment: It cant act on items that are not in the DOM yet, and it has no idea that a new DOM element has been added unless you use a watcher. To watch for changes in an element after page load, you can use the delegate() method. However - to ensure that the entire page is loaded before firing jQuery - you need to place it in the ready wrapper.

Comment: Admittedly I'm 100% sure why this occurs in the context of the rest of your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your code within the document.ready method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```